What is the stance of Hinduism on discussing philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?
What are the rules or guidelines on how a Hindu should engage with others who would like to discuss philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?

Are Hindus allowed to discuss / engage in the ideas to some degree? Or is it shunned.
How does Hinduism incorporate ideas outside the main canon / system? (Generally speaking)
Are certain topics to be never discussed?

This would help me ask better questions to the Hindu community in general, but also would serve as a gauge as to how to interact. Basically, what is acceptable conversation topics in the end.

In classical Hinduism, non-Hindus are considered as mlecchas i.e barbarians who are portrayed to be devoid of the basic notion between right & wrong, hence nothing from their civilisations are ought to be incorporated into the Hindu civilisational ethos. Up until recently, even interaction with non-believers was extremely shunned & was punished with banishment from the society of believers. This extreme disdain for non-believers was likely a reaction to frequent foreign invasions in midst of political instability (perpetual in medieval India) in order to preserve their own identity & religion.

Historian R. C. Majumdar commenting on the condition of Hindus living under Bengal Sultanate, stated that while Muslims actively studied Arabic translations on Greek works of Plato, Aristotle & Plotinus, the same wasn't seen among the Hindus, since they had adopted a policy of completely shunning any foreign influence & minimizing all sorts of contact with non-believers in response to the brutality of the Islamic theocracy. In pre-Islamic india, Hindu kingdoms engaged in extensive maritime trade, but under Muslim rule, Hindu authorities banned overseas travelling to reduce alien influence.

As a native of Bengal, I can give you some examples of the level Hindus here went to shun Islamic influence. Genealogical records of Brahmins kept by matchmakers called upon to boycott not only descendants of those families, whose even a single female member had been kidnapped or raped by Muslims & male members had been forcibly converted to Islam, but also descendants of the people from that very same village where the disgraced family lived at the time of the events, in a system called mela-pratha. Some religious authorities went as far as to criminalise verbal interaction with Muslims.

Given the extent to which Hindu society went to isolate itself from foreign influence, it isn't surprising that Hindu philosophy has been relatively free from foreign influence & vociferously opposes it.  However, the attitudes changed during British rule. Now the Muslims had started to shun British influence, & a large number of Hindus who saw the British as liberating them from Muslim tyranny & establishing political stability, readily assimilated Enlightenment ideals of the age, thereby making them to re-evaluate Hindu religion on the basis of the Enlightenment. But this isn't universal.

2nd answer - Europeans just simply couldn't ignore the influence of ancient Greek philosophy, so they portrayed the philosophers as 'virtuous pagans' to justify studying their ideas. But such thing isn't found in Hinduism, for it states that mlecchas are extremely depraved & have nothing inherently good in them. A good example is a line on the compendium on penitence called Prayascittaviveka, authored by the 15th century Bengali Hindu scholar Sulapani, which states that mlecchas aren't required to observe penitence for commiting any sort of sins, for doing sinful deeds is inherent to them.

And Hinduism has a very strong notion on scriptural authority. Incorporating anything non-canonical is considered as outright heresy. Sikhism which incorporated Islamic ideas of iconophobia & priesthood of all believers isn't considered to be a part of Hindu philosophy.

3rd answer - Practically everything related to Hinduism has been questioned at some point of time. Hindus have become prone to their faith being questioned disparagingly by Buddhists & Jains in medieval times and Muslims, Christians & materialists in the present, and criticising Hinduiam has never punishable by death. Hindus have a rich tradition of indulging in scholarly constructive debates among themselves & others. But if you want to ask questions on this platform, I would personally ask you to refrain from asking questions on caste, for it is a very polarising topic causing disturbance.
